# Best A* heuristic : multiple targets and agents

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, maze, heuristics

I have a problem consisting of a square maze with walls, targets and agents. Agents can only move horizontally/vertically. At each step, each agent moves from 1 square.

I have to implement an A* algorithm to solve the problem and I struggle to find a good heuristic to solve it.

Everytime I read documentation about best heuristics, it always concerns a maze with only one agent and multiple targets but nothing about multiple agents.

The heuristic I try to experiment is the following :

For each target, I take the closest Manathan distance from an agent and I sum the result.

In this case, if there's two targets remaining and three agents, it only take two agents in the sum and the farthest agent is not considered, the sum will be less than a case with three agents and three targets remaining.

According to the definition of an admissible heuristic, I doubt mine is admissible.

I find it reasonable because it considers each food and not only one, but I think I'm missing an important point.

Anyone has tips or interesting approach to consider ?

Answer (score 0):

A* only works with one agent.  You'll need to run a separate search instance for each agent.

If there are lots of agents and only a few targets, and your graph is undirected, you could search from the targets to the agents instead *(assuming you only need the closest agent)* and then reverse the results.

If you need to path-find with lots and **lots** of agents, you should use a different algorithm.  There are lots of choices; the keywords to look for here are "swarm pathfinding", "crowd flow", and "boids".  Generally you'll create a vector field for the entire map, and couple that with some sort of avoidance algorithm.

Comment: I don't have choice in the algorithm, A* is mandatored and this is maximum 3 agents.